# Parse, how to store user's device model in Parse dashboard?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is there a way to store user's device model (that can be accessed with `Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL`) in parse dashboard where users installation data stores?

I can create a string column in dashboard but how to send the data from app to that column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ParseInstallation class to send this data to Parse.

Example:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("deviceModel",deviceModelString);
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Where "deviceModel" is the name of your column in the Dashboard.

Hope it helps you! :)